# cant start tunnelmanager in Mysql workbench during connection creation

Tags: mysql, opensuse

I am using opensuse 11.3, I have installed Mysql workbench through compiling source,when i am creating new database connection its showing

> can't start SSH tunnel manager

what should i do ?

Comment: are you able to access db from mysql cmd? SHOW DATABASES;? What Mysql workbench version you used?

Comment: Yes,i am able to able to access,i am using mysql workbench 5.2.45

Comment: Check this: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60379

Comment: i faced similar problem  installing 'python-paramiko' package solved that problem.try this search for python-paramiko in yast.Install
python-paramiko - SSH2 Module for Python

Comment: Thanks @gYanI, ya i was missing this file,now its working ......